# Reload data in GXT grid freezes

Tags: gwt, load, grid, freeze, gxt

Based on the GXT showcase example 'Paging BeanModel Grid' I try to reload the grid when I have done a modifiaction to my data source. I defined the loader like that:

```
final BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>> loader = 
    new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>>(proxy, new BeanModelReader());
loader.setRemoteSort(true);
```

The data loads correctly.

When I do:

```
loader.load();
```

My paging toolbar just freezes and goes disabled, the grid freezes too and displays what appears to be a loading mask.

I tried to add some events to force a double reload without luck:

```
grid.addListener(Events.Attach, new Listener<GridEvent<ModelData>>() {
    public void handleEvent(GridEvent<ModelData> be) {
        loader.load(); 
    }
});
```

I tried to use the reconfigure(store,cm) option as well and same result.

Any help?

Thanks,
Jordi.

Comment: try passing the paging offset and limit, like so `loader.load(0, 50)`, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading bar grays out so you can see it is working, and the grid may also have a loading message. The code that is working is the server, probably preparing the items.

Set logging messages in your server code (RPC servlet probably), at the beginning and at the end of the call, to see how long they take to run. That is likely where the actual 'freeze' is actually happening, based on the info in your question.

There could be a pause in the browser after that time as well, but in that case the loading circle would stop moving.

Comment: The server code is working fine. Actually it is exactly the same call in both cases. I double checked the RPC response with firebug and it contains valid data. No server nor JS exceptions.

Comment: You may need to post more code then - something is wired differently than the examples you based your code on, which works correctly. If it isn't the server, and the server is working and sending good data, then it must be the client. If the loading animation is still working, then the data was ignored by something, if it isn't spinning, then the client is stuck in a loop somewhere, and is actually frozen.

Comment: Probem solved: There was an exception in the RPC, the Proxy silents is and I was not seeing it on the trace. GXT should unsilent it. Thanks.

Comment: A LoadException listener should point that issue out to you - did that event not fire, or were you not listening for it? Often there can be business logic reasons for emitting an exception, and so it doesn't make sense to log every exception, but to instead check firebug, server logs, and LoadException events.

Answer (score 0):

To me there is a bug on the grid controller:

Code details:

```
private final BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>> loader;
private Grid<ModelData> grid;
[...]

public ListUsersView(RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<UserTableEntryBean>> proxy) {
        // Create loader
        loader = new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>>(proxy, new BeanModelReader());
        loader.setRemoteSort(true);

        // Create store
        store = new ListStore<ModelData>(loader);

        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        layout.setMargins(new Margins(3, 0, 0, 0));
        this.setLayout(layout);

        final PagingToolBar toolBar = new PagingToolBar(50);
        toolBar.bind(loader);

        List<ColumnConfig> columns = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
        columns.add(new ColumnConfig(UserTableEntryBean.Fields.username.name(), "Username", 100));
        columns.add(new ColumnConfig(UserTableEntryBean.Fields.email.name(), "E-mail", 200));
        ColumnConfig date = new ColumnConfig(UserTableEntryBean.Fields.creationDate.name(), "Creation date", 100);
        date.setDateTimeFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/y"));
        columns.add(date);

        ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(columns);

        grid = new Grid<ModelData>(store, cm);

        grid.setLoadMask(true);
        grid.setBorders(true);
        grid.setAutoExpandColumn(UserTableEntryBean.Fields.creationDate.name());

        [...]
}

public boolean refreshTable() {
        return loader.load();
}
```